# Making a vector from unformatted elements in Python

Tags: python, arrays, vector

```
base_url = 'http://www.baseball-reference.com' # base url for concatenation
data = requests.get("http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BAL/2014-schedule-scores.shtml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)

url = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):

    if not link.has_attr('href'):
        continue

    if link.get_text() != 'boxscore':
        continue

    url = base_url + link['href']
```

When printing url this is what I get.

http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/BAL/BAL201403310.shtml

http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/BAL/BAL201404020.shtml

http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/BAL/BAL201404030.shtml

http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/DET/DET201404040.shtml
...

http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/KCA/KCA201410150.shtml

If I loop through this it gives me single elements, I understand why, but i need to make a vector with each element being the full url for each boxscore. What is the best way to do this? Should I append the first 62 elements, then next 62, so on and so forth. Im not sure what the best method is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
url = base_url + link['href']
```

to

```
url.append(base_url + link['href'])
```